# ESTA related questions

Tags: visas, usa, esta

I will be going to New York in August. A few of my friends are coming but since one of them went to Somalia a few years ago (after march 2011 for sure) he's got an interview for a visa.

We'll be staying there for a week for tourism purposes.

I was applying for an ESTA but on the form, an address of stay was required and right now, we're not sure if my friend will pass the interview. We all hold British but he holds a Dutch passport. If not coming makes a difference in our stay since price/hotel/airbnb rooms etc

I wanted to know if theres any way of me filling out the esta form without knowing the address of where I'll be staying at the moment? And also, how long does it take for the esta to get accepted?

Answer (score 2):

" If you do not have a U.S. point of contact, you may complete this question by answering “unknown" "

This link is about evus, but the same applies for esta: https://www.cbp.gov/faqs/order-complete-evus-form-i-need-us-point-contact-i-don-t-have-immediate-plans-travel-united